# How to write a link to a public file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

In my Rails app, I have some files in the /public directory which I want to write hyperlinks to in the views. How do I do this other than writing old HTML like `<a href...`

Is there a neat `link_to` way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using the anchor element, after all that's what `link_to` outputs anyway. However, you should just be able to do:

```
<%= link_to 'Some File', '/some_file.zip' %>
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer if the site is deployed within a subdirectory.